# Why won't my Ruby script execute?

Tags: ruby, bash, shebang, env

So, I made a simply ruby script,

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

puts "Hello!"
```

When I try to run it in terminal it doesn't put "Hello!" on the screen.  I have tried entering `chmod +x test.rb` (`test.rb` is the name of my file). When I run it, it doesn't give me an error, it just doesn't display "Hello!". Any help will be much appreciated. I have looked everywhere for a possible answer, and I have found nothing so far.

Comment: Works for me. Same code. I am running it with ``./test.rb``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd guess that you're trying to run it as just `test` like this:

```
$ test
```

But [`test` is a bash builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#index-test) command that doesn't produce any output, it just sets a return value. If you run your script properly:

```
$ ./test.rb
```

then you'll see something. Note the explicit `./` path, the current directory is rarely (and hopefully never) in your `PATH` so you need to say `./` to run something in the current directory (unless of course you're in `/bin`, `/usr/bin`, etc.).

---

In the comments you say that there are some <kbd>Ctrl+M</kbd> characters in your script:

```
$ cat -e test.rb
#!/usr/bin/env ruby^M^Mputs "Hello!"
```

I don't see any `$`s in that `cat -e` output so you don't have any actual end-of-line markers, just some carriage-return characters (that's the `^M`). A single CR is an old MacOS end-of-line, Windows uses a CR-LF pair, and Unix (including OSX) uses just a single LF to mark the end of a line of text. Since you don't have any EOLs, the shell just sees a single line that looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby ...
```

without an actual script for `ruby` to run, the shell just sees the shebang comment and nothing else. The result is that nothing noticeable happens when you run your script. Fix your EOLs and your script will start working sensibly. You might also want to look at your editor's settings so that it starts writing proper EOLs.

Comment: My script is saved as test.rb in  a folder named programs. This is a copy of my terminal:
unknown20c9d0cc586f:programs carlosguillen$ ruby test.rb
unknown20c9d0cc586f:programs carlosguillen$ ./test.rb
As you can see nothing is outputted to the screen. The file contains the original script.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. Are you certain that `test.rb` contains only what you think it contains? Have you checked for anything strange with `cat -e test.rb`?

Comment: Thanks for your response. This is what I get after I enter cat -e test.rb: unknown20c9d0cc586f:programs carlosguillen$ cat -e test.rb
#!/usr/bin/env ruby^M^Mputs "Hello!"unknown20c9d0cc586f:programs carlosguillen$. I don't have "^M^M" in the program.

Answer (score 0):

How are you calling this method. You would want to call this out by something like `ruby test.rb` if you are in the directory with the test.rb file. Another general tip for trying something out that doesn't work would be to go into irb on command line and try your program, like `puts "Hello!` to see if it is that particular code that is the problem.