# Ruby script won't execute

Tags: ruby, terminal

New to Ruby. I have created a very simple script called "hello.rb":

```
name = "Frederik"
puts = "Hello #{name}"
```

It will not execute (there is no output) in my terminal when I run "ruby hello.rb". I have checked that my editor (atom) is creating EOL's using "cat -e hello.rb" as suggested by "mu is too short" here: [Why won't my Ruby script execute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18705194/why-wont-my-ruby-script-execute). What could be causing this? I have attached a screenshot for reference.

[image: Screenshot]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
puts = "Hello #{name}"
```

You're assigning "Hello #{name}" to a variable named puts, not writing it to STDIO.

remove the assignment operator and your output should display normally.

Comment: Thanks mcfinnigan - appreciate it